# Unable to find matching script for this artifact inscription

Tags: translation, character-identification

I need help getting this translated. I think it's a lesser seal or even Hong Shan era. Attempts to translate by myself have failed to match the script.

[image: stone turtle shell carving]

Answer (score 1):

turn it upside down:

[image]

the middle one is 㞢 (u+37a2), which means “have, exist”

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=㞢](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E3%9E%A2)

the lower one is 屮 (u+5c6e), which is the original of “草” (grass); in context, it means grass or wood

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=屮](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B1%AE)

the top one is not yet identified, most likely is a location related character.

have fun :)

Comment: I'd tentatively offer 日出屮 > 日出草, on the grounds that, apparently and as far as I can remember, 之止出 are often not distinguished in older forms of the Chinese script (as eg in 武 which was humorously identified as 止戈 in a locus classicus but should probably be understood as 出戈), and 屮 is one half of 艸, modern 草, because, well even my crappy Linux IME here allows me to write 屮 by entering `cao`. Understand 屮 as 草地 and the sentence writes, in as simple forms as possible, "the sun is rising from the grasslands".

Comment: @john frazer, nice try :) well, “出” in oracle bone, bronze, small seal script are more complicated than  “㞢”. http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=出. “日”, it can’t convince me. actually, the character “西” in bronze script is on my mind (except the internal component) http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=西

Comment: The image shows a pointy upper end, it is true, but it lacks the crisscrossing lines; I find http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=日 much closer. Over at http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=㞢: "之 出也。象艸過屮，枝莖益大，有所之。一者，地也。" As shown on https://www.zdic.net/hans/俑?q=之, the Shuowen seal character is *very* close to 㞢 and the humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk source identifies the two that 许深 associated with 出. https://www.zdic.net/hans/俑?q=屮 gives "屮 chè 草木刚长出来。 cǎo 古同“草”。", so I still find my reading plausible.

Comment: @JohnFrazer This entire question is basically unanswerable - the text segment is too short and we're not sure of the context. It might not even be Chinese. If I had to give an interpretation, it would be the transcription 白㞢（之）屮.

Comment: Also, consider the interpretation 白（伯？）㞢（有）又（祐）.